# Python: error in using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have written a function and I try to call it some times but it returns me an error.

```
# create a graph with all active nodes

G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100, 0.05)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
G.add_nodes_from(G.nodes(), color='blue')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, G.nodes(), node_size=20, node_color='b')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.3)

def step(G, x, y):
color = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'color')
for (key, value) in zip(color, color.values()):
    if value == 'blue':
        neighbours = G.neighbors(key)
        inactive_neighbours = []
        for n in neighbours:
            if color[n] == 'red':
                inactive_neighbours.append(n)
                if inactive_neighbours:
                    chosen_neighbour = random.sample(neighbours, 1)
                    if np.random.random() < x / (x + y):
                        activate = []
                        activate.append(chosen_neighbour)
                        G.add_nodes_from(activate, color='blue')

        if np.random.random() < y / (x + y):
            deactivate = []
            deactivate.append(key)
            G.add_nodes_from(deactivate, color='red')

print(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'color'))
i = 3
while 2 < i < 100:
    step(G, 0.5, 1)
    i += 1

step(G, 0.5, 1)
```

And it returns me error
`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`.
What I do wrong?
How can I call to function to execute it some time?

Comment: Can you give the complete stack trace ? Not able to figure out which line threw this error.

Comment: I'd have a look at what exactly `zip(color, color.values())` gives. I suspect that that line is the culprit.

Comment: @Afaq it all code, but without import libraries

Comment: @karlson color is a dictionary and it looks like `{0: 'red', 1: 'blue', 2: 'red', 3: 'red', 4: 'red', 5: 'red', 6: 'red', 7: 'red', 8: 'red', 9: 'blue', 10: 'red', 11: 'blue', 12: 'red', 13: 'red', 14: 'blue', 15: 'red', 16: 'red', 17: 'red', 18: 'red', 19: 'red', 20: 'red', 21: 'red', 22: 'red', 23: 'red', 24: 'blue', 25: 'red', 26: 'blue', 27: 'red', 28: 'blue', 29: 'blue', 30: 'red', 31: 'red', 32: 'red', 33: 'red', 34: 'red', 35: 'red', 36: 'blue', 37: 'red', 38: 'blue', 39: 'red', 40: 'red', 41: 'red', 42: 'red', 43: 'blue', 44: 'blue'}
`

Comment: Use the `items()` method of the dictionary instead.